# Convert byte array of zeros and ones (0,1) to string of zeros and ones

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a big byte array of zeros and one to a string variable.

```
private Random _random;
private string _str;

private void Convert(byte[] bytes)
{
    for (var index = 0; index < 10000000; index++)
    {
        var b = bytes[index];                
        _str += b.ToString();

    }            
}
```

But its performance is very low.

Is it possible to convert a big array to string variable with 'unsafe' or 'fixed' keywords? (use memory allocation)

Comment: Maybe this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: I have a feeling there's a linq one-liner that can do this, but the simple performance fix to your code is to use a StringBuilder instead of appending to an ordinary string.

Comment: Why did you remove relevant code? Anyway, use a stringbuilder, not `string += string`.

Comment: Perhaps `String.Join("", bytes.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2)))`?

Comment: And when you use a string builder you can exactly set the initial buffer size.

Comment: @CodeCaster 'stringbuilder' worked for me.